# Can anyone helpme to set up HoloEverywhere on android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-holo-everywhere

I followed the tutorial from `HoloEverywhere` in the Git page:

Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA

- Checkout from Version Control - Git
- Typo in Repository URL: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere.git
- Press 'Clone', wait until repository checkout
- If you use Android Studio, then just click 'Yes' on the proposal to open a project. Otherwise in IDEA press Import project and specify path to downloaded repo, choose gradle model and press next.
- Mark checkbox Use auto-import and click finish.
  Kiss a Google and Android devs team!
- Read this basic migration guide.

But I can´t make it work. I try to use the same method like ABS, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's quite easy. Just download the source code. Use Android Studio to import HoloEverywhere project by selecting the `build.gradle` file in the root folder and you are all set. Android Studio will build it automatically. If you want to run, then you have to setup Android Studio to do so, you can refer to Android Studio [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).